# (Angularjs Metronic) Sidebar Sub Menu hiding after click and not keep open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, metronic

The problem is simply that after you click the sidebar, the submenu appears briefly and is hidden again.

*Layout.js (slideUp func.) is triggered twice nonsense*

I checked the settings in app.js and the id of the menus. I am sure that the id and sub id that I have stored in the database are working correctly. I checked that the classes on the page worked properly and placed correctly.

But there is a problem with the "open" class and its associated "display block" style. If I go to fix it and remain in the metronic layout.css, the important typing remains visible. But before it opens and closes again.

Thank you for your help.

-Metronic.factory in app.js

```
var settings = {
            layout: {
                pageSidebarClosed: false, // sidebar menu state
                pageBodySolid: false, // solid body color state
                pageAutoScrollOnLoad: 1000 // auto scroll to top on page load
            },
            ...
        };
```

-MetronicApp.controller in app.js

```
    MetronicApp.controller('SidebarController', 
    ['$scope', 'authService', function ($scope, authService) {    

    $scope.SelectMenu = function (id) {
        $scope.selectedMenu = id;
    }

    $scope.SelectChildMenu = function (id) {
        $scope.selectedChildMenu = id;
    }

    $scope.LoadMenus = function () {
        authService.UserMenus().then(function (response) {
                $scope.menus = response;
                Layout.initSidebar(); // init sidebar
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("Error");
            });
    };
    }]);
```

- Sidebar view (.html)

  ```
  <div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="page-sidebar-menu" data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" ng-class="{'page-sidebar-menu-closed': settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed}" ng-controller="SidebarController" ng-init="LoadMenus()">
          <li class="start" ng:repeat="m in menus" ng-class="{'active open': m.id==selectedMenu}">
              <a href={{m.menuAction}} ng-click="SelectMenu(m.id)" >
                  <i class="icon-home"></i>
                  <span class="title">{{m.menuText}}</span>
              </a>
              <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                  <li ng:repeat="child in m.children" ng-class="{'active': child.id==selectedChildMenu}" >                        
                      <a  ui-sref="{{child.menuAction}}"    >
                          <i class="icon-home"></i>
                          <span class="title">{{child.menuText}}</span>
                      </a>    
                  </li>
              </ul>    
          </li>        
      </ul>
  </div>
  ```
- layout.js (Metronic theme global script)

  ```
  if (sub.is(":visible")) {
              jQuery('.arrow', the).removeClass("open");
              the.parent().removeClass("open");
              debugger;// **This is also triggered immediately after a single click**
              sub.slideUp(slideSpeed, function () {
                  if (autoScroll === true && $('body').hasClass('page-sidebar-closed') === false) {
                      if ($('body').hasClass('page-sidebar-fixed')) {
                          menu.slimScroll({
                              'scrollTo': (the.position()).top
                          });
                      } else {
                          Metronic.scrollTo(the, slideOffeset);
                      }
                  }
                  handleSidebarAndContentHeight();
              });
          } else if (hasSubMenu) {
              debugger; //first visit here normally
              jQuery('.arrow', the).addClass('open');
              the.parent().addClass('open');
              sub.slideDown(slideSpeed, function () {
                  if (autoScroll === true && $('body').hasClass('page-sidebar-closed') === false) {
                      if ($('body').hasClass('page-sidebar-fixed')) {
                          menu.slimScroll({
                              'scrollTo': (the.position()).top
                          });
                      } else {
                          Metronic.scrollTo(the, slideOffeset);
                      }
                  }
                  handleSidebarAndContentHeight();
              });
          }
          e.preventDefault();
      });
  ```

CSS Flow Logs (Working and not working versions)

[Working version:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UW5ZW.png)

[Broken version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGG3K.png)

Comment: By the way, sidebar hover menu work properly. But i need default sidebar

Comment: LoadMenus triggered twice in app.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete ng-controller="sidebarController" expression if other views have ( main.html as me )